# Update charts in PowerPoint in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a couple charts in a powerpoint presentation that I want to write a macro for to update them automatically.  I have a database that will export data as excel spreadsheets and I was wondering if there was a way in either excel vba or powerpoint vba to have the user input the location of the new data file and have that new data copied and pasted so that the chart will update.  I am new to VBA so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by editing link to the ppt charts to the new file.

Simply go to the

> > Excel Option Button>>Prepare>>Edit Links to Files and change source of the charts to the new file.

Let me know if you still want/need to use VBA for this.

Cheers